# Number of children 0 should be 5 what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am just splashing around doing baby things. Currently I am working on a custom slider with 5 "div" tags inside of a "li" element.

**HTML**

```
<li class="slider">
    <div class="first inactive text-center">
         <img src="img/wilson-logo.jpg" alt="wilson logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="second active text-center">
         <img src="img/head-logo.jpg" alt="head logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="third inactive text-center">
         <img src="img/prince-logo.jpg" alt="prince logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="second active text-center hide">
         <img src="img/head-logo.jpg" alt="head logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="third inactive text-center hide">
         <img src="img/prince-logo.jpg" alt="prince logo"/>
    </div>
  </li>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#slider").ready(function (){
    var slides = $("#slider").children();

    $("#backwards").click(function(){
        alert(slides.length);
    });
});
```

My jQuery alert reads (0)... I am expecting 5, what I am eventually trying to accomplish is to get ALL "div" elements into an array called "slides" then I would like two display three of them. But for not can someone just explain to me why is it reading 0 instead of 5. Thank you

**COMPLETED SLIDER ANY SUGGESTIONS?**
I have completed the slider you can see the sample here: http://www.iamcavic.com/simon at the bottom of the page (Friends and Partners) logo slider..

I have learned some new things like get child by element like children('div') and .each() to loop all elements, also I have learned .html() to retrieve the content of the element.

Here is my **jQuery**

```
$(".slider").ready(function (){

    var images = [], i = 1;

    // Initial loop to get all <img> elements out of child <div> tags
    $(".slider").children('div').each(function() {
        images[i] = $(this).html(); 
        i++;
    });

    // Initialize controls and positions of windows 1,2,3
    var position_one = 1, position_two = 2, position_three = 3, num_images = images.length;

    // Go backwards control
    $("#backwards").click(function(){

        // Check positions for and reset
        if (position_one === 1) {
            position_one = num_images;
        }else if (position_two === 1){
            position_two = num_images;
        }else if (position_three === 1){
            position_three = num_images;};

        // Move position back - 1 on all windows
        position_one--;
        position_two--;
        position_three--;

        $("#one").html(images[position_one]);
        $("#two").html(images[position_two]);
        $("#three").html(images[position_three]);

    });

    // Go forward control
    $("#forwards").click(function(){

        // Check positions for and reset
        if(position_one === (num_images - 1 )){
            position_one = 0;
        }else if(position_two === (num_images - 1 )){
            position_two = 0;
        }else if(position_three === (num_images - 1 )){
            position_three = 0;
        }

        // Move positions forward + 1 on all windows
        position_one++;
        position_two++;
        position_three++;

        $("#one").html(images[position_one]);
        $("#two").html(images[position_two]);
        $("#three").html(images[position_three]);

    });
});
```

I am wondering what would you suggest and I'm sure there is a better way of doing this. I am open for any suggestions and recommendations for the future projects.

Thanks one again!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was using the ID selector instead of the class selector. The question won't be of much use to anyone else.

Comment: Felix, I didn't know what the problem was so I worded it the best way I could. It is off topic, I will try to edit the title. I guess PSL already fixed the title. Thank you all for helping, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I finished my task, I would be interested to hear suggestions and recommendations for future references. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be `$('.slider')`.  Class not ID.

ID selector = `'#name'`
Class selector = `'.name'.`

Comment: thank you this works and teaches me something :).. I didn't know that so thank you.. I will accept this answer in 12min

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `ready()` function on the `document` object.

This is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slides = $("li.slider").children();

    $("#backwards").click(function(){
        alert(slides.length);
    });
});
```

Comment: slider.ready isn't incorrect, and would work. Document.ready is just standard practice, especially when the code is in the head. Don't need any ready statements when the code comes after all of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`#` references an id, but on your li element, slider is a class, so you should use `.` Which references a class.

Answer (score 0):

You have define your main div with a class `.slider`, but in your jQuery, you're using an ID `#slider`...

Here's your javascript fixed:

```
$(".slider").ready(function (){
    var slides = $("#slider").children();

    $("#backwards").click(function(){
        alert(slides.length);
    });
});
```

You can also use `$(document).ready(...)` in that case, and the portion of code will be execute when the page will be ready (that's why you want)